# Regular expression to match and remove duplicate words

Tags: java, regex

While working on a question to remove duplicate words in a sentence, I found this solution :

```
(?i)(\b\w+\b)(\s+\1\b)+
```

So lets say the sentence is

> She left LEft leFT now

Now, as far as I understand, the 1st group - **"(\b\w+\b)"** matches **"left"** as it should be a boundary character followed by one or more word characters followed by a boundary character again; and 2nd group **"(\s+\1\b)"** matches **"LEft leFT"** as it should be (one or more spaces followed by the group 1 match followed by a boundary character) - repeated one or more times.

But when I try to print them like this :

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println (m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2));
}
```

The result I expected is

> left - LEft leFT

But the actual result is

> left -  leFT

Can someone explain how this's is happening.

Comment: Repeated capturing groups in Java only store the last iteration value.

Comment: Group 2 contains `" leFT", see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b9XrRB/1).

Comment: This will get what you want : `(?i)\b(\w+)((?:\s+\1\b)+)`.  Note how the repeated group is captured into group 2.